# Add notes using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

everyone. I'm looking for a way to make notes in excel worksheet, using python. Found a way to add comments, but I need notes like on screenshot. Is there an easy way to add them using openpyxl or any other lib? [screenshot of a note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP5ys.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating this because this post is the top google result

The openpyxl docs incorrectly refer to notes as comments. Just follow the instructions in the docs on how to add comments: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comments.html. There is one issue with their example code though in the docs, so use the below code instead:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.comments import Comment
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
comment = Comment('This is the comment text', 'Comment Author')
ws["A1".comment] = comment
wb.save('your_file.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to accomplish the same thing. Apparently that "note" is the same as data validation as described in the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html#examples).

So what you do is:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

wb = load_workbook('my_sheets.xlsx')

# Create 'note'
dv = DataValidation()
dv.errorTitle = 'Your note title'
dv.error = 'Your note body'

# Add 'note' to A1 in the active sheet
dv.add(wb.active['A1'])

# This is required also, or you won't see the note
wb.active.add_data_validation(dv)

wb.save('my_sheet_with_note.xlsx')
```

It also mentions prompts, which is something you can look into:

```py
# Optionally set a custom prompt message
dv.promptTitle = 'List Selection'
dv.prompt = 'Please select from the list'
```

**Edit:** I updated the answer with a part of the code that solved my problem at the time:

```py
def add_note(cell, prompt_title='', prompt=''):
    p = {
        'promptTitle': prompt_title[:32],
        'prompt': prompt[:255],
    }
    dv = DataValidation(**p)
    dv.add(cell)
    cell.parent.add_data_validation(dv)
```

Comment: I tried your example, but it didn't work. Then i went to docs and tried their example and it partially worked. It seams that (i suppose) with my settings it doesn't show error message. However, if using prompts, excel will display them, but only if you click on a cell with prompt activated.

Comment: I'm wrestling with this now.  Did you ever mind a way to get notes working?  Thanks!

Comment: I looked into some code that I worked on at the time. I updated the initial answer.